# InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type en C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Buen dia
Tengo el siguiente problema, al intentar ejecutar el siguiente controlador me lleva a la siguiente:

> EXCEPTION InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type ...

Creo que es algo muy sencillo de resolver pero  tengo muy poco en c# y ASP:NET Core ya que al ejecutar el controlador sin la fuincion asincrona todo es correcto.

```
public async Task <IEnumerable<FamiliaViewsModel>> GetFamilia()
    {
        var familias = await _context.Familia.ToListAsync();
        return familias.Select(f => new FamiliaViewsModel
        {
            Nombre = f.Nombre
        });


    }
 public partial class Familia
{
    public Familia()
    {
        Subfamilia = new HashSet<Subfamilia>();
    }

    public int FamiliaId { get; set; }
    public string Nombre { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Subfamilia> Subfamilia { get; set; }
}

 public class FamiliaViewsModel
{
    public int FamiliaId { get; set; }
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
}
```

Alguien podría apoyarme con el error que estoy cometiendo,esto para que no me vuelva a pasar en un futuro.

Comment: En que linea se da el error?

Comment: Es lo que quisiera saber.

Comment: Hace un debug de tu controlador y fijate en donde tira el error

Comment: Agrega como invocas al controlador,

Comment: al Return al final del select lo converti en un List con ToListAsync y  ya no me dio error,pero la verdad nose por que dejo de darme error

Answer (score 2):

Si tal y como indicas en la pregunta, el problema lo tienes cuando el método `GetFamilia()` lo transformas en asíncrono (`async`), intenta simplificar el código de acceso a datos en **una única llamada asíncrona**:

```
public async Task <IEnumerable<FamiliaViewsModel>> GetFamilia()
{
    return await _context.Familia.Select(f => new FamiliaViewsModel
    {
        Nombre = f.Nombre
    }).ToListAsync();
}
```

Comment: Hola Rafael, pero por que pasa eso ?, es lo que no entiendo, me podrias ayudar con la razón de esto.

Comment: @ivanyañez: Hola, la asincronía es así, requiere de un una única llamada asíncrona para una sola respuesta `async` para que sea optimo. Aun así, revisa los datos que traes en la clase `Familia`, ya que tienes un subconjunto de `ICollection<Subfamilia> Subfamilia` que también pude estar dando problemas (dead lock).